# Allow calling any constructor for all array elements

Tags: c++

After some investigation, looks like the behavior initializing variables follows some convention.

For single element:

```
auto* x = new int; // undefined value
auto* x = new int{}; // 0 (default initializer)
auto* x = new int(23); // 23 (copy initializer)

auto* x = new Test; // default constructor
auto* x = new Test{}; // default constructor
auto* x = new Test(...); // X constructor (overload-chosen)
```

This makes a lot of sense, until you try to apply the same logic on arrays:

```
auto* x = new int[10]; // all undefined values - OK
auto* x = new int[10]{}; // all 0 (default initializer) - OK
auto* x = new int[10](23); // all 23 (copy initializer on all) - NOT IMPLEMENTED

auto* x = new Test[10]; // default constructors - OK
auto* x = new Test[10]{}; // default constructors - OK
auto* x = new Test[10](...); // X constructor on all (overload-chosen) - NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

My logic says that you can make some assumptions:

- If a type can be constructed using `T(Args..)` then every element from the array can be constructed. There is no reason to not allow `T[N](Args...)` syntax.

Does anyone know why this feature doesn't exist? It would be very nice to allow

```
new int[10](23); // all 23
new Test[10]("asd", 123); // construct all using Test("asd", 123)
```

Edit: The whole idea of this is to avoid the default initialization/constructor and call the one we need directly.

Comment: In practice, just use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.

Comment: @Angew yep, but that's a workaround haha I want to know why the language itself doesn't allow this

Comment: Nothing's stopping you from writing a proposal and submitting it to the C++ standards committee if you really think this would be super useful for everyone.

Comment: @IvanSanz Not really. The thing is, except for the most resource-constrained situations, the normal way of spelling "dynamic array" in C++ is `std::vector`. `new []` has *very* few legitimate uses, so it's not really worth practical consideration. Still, I consider the quesiton interesting on the theoretical basis (and I've upvoted it).

Comment: C++ doesn't have it because it is rarely needed in practice and additional complication of language rules is just not worth it. If you want, you can define your own std::array-like class that does it.

Comment: The nitpick in me wants to say that the values are not random at all in the first cases. They are undefined. Random makes it sound like there's actually a random generator setting them to some values.

Answer (score 4):

While it would be nice if there was something for this in the standard library<sup><sup>†</sup></sup>, the functionality you want is relatively straightforward to implement:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, typename... ArgTs, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto make_filled_array(ArgTs const&... args, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> {
        return {{(Is, T(args...))...}};
    }
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename... ArgTs, std::enable_if_t<N != 0, int> = 0>
constexpr auto make_filled_array(ArgTs const&... args) {
    return detail::make_filled_array<T, ArgTs...>(args..., std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

// ...

auto arr1 = make_filled_array<int, 10>(23);
auto arr2 = make_filled_array<Test, 10>("asd", 123);
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/122865fc11ced260)**</kbd>

That said, I don't see any point to taking constructor arguments here; container `emplace` functions are useful because they do perfect-forwarding, but we can't do that here because we need to reuse the arguments for each constructor call (so moving from them is not an option). I think copy-construction is natural:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto make_filled_array(T const& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> {
        return {{(Is, t)...}};
    }
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T, std::enable_if_t<N != 0, int> = 0>
constexpr auto make_filled_array(T const& t) {
    return detail::make_filled_array(t, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

// ...

auto arr1 = make_filled_array<10>(23);
auto arr2 = make_filled_array<10>(Test{"asd", 123});
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a62d1bc74b4cca24)**</kbd>

N.b. your use of `new` implies that you may be from a managed language and need to read up on value semantics. ;-] This code *could* be altered to return a `std::array<T, N>*` or `T*` (or even `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` for something moderately reasonable), but, why would one..? Just use `std::vector<T>`:

```
std::vector<int> vec(10, 23);
```

I chose to demonstrate `std::array<>` here because your examples all have a constant size.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup></sup> The closest thing that comes to mind is `std::fill`, but that wouldn't *initialize* the array...

Comment: Where does it exhibit the most vexing parse?

Comment: @interjay : You're right; I'm _that_ not used to seeing code with `new` that I temporarily blocked it out. ;-]

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array  and http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0325r0.html So we need to wait,,,

Comment: I think this is clearly the best way to fix this in modern C++, rather than hack on the already over-complicated language initialization rules

Comment: Very clever use of evaluation rules in `(Is, t)...`. I had to stop for a while to realize why you pair object with index. For others: It simply ignores `Is` value because `,` always returns last expression but it's needed to repeat `t` argument `Is` times

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for the committee, but I can see a case where your syntax would be very very **problematic**: initializing from **temporaries:** .

```
X* x = new X[10](Y{});
```

How do you deal with this case?

You can't call `X(Y&&)` (assuming it exists) for each of the 10 elements because you have only 1 temporary and all elements after the first would be initialized from an object in an unspecified state.

The other alternative would be to somehow call `X(const Y&)` instead (assuming again it exists). Besides over complicating the standard and adding unexpected inconsistent behavior that just opens up another can of worms. The `X` object could have a reference bind to our `Y{}` assuming is an lvalue and you end up with a dangling reference.

The only viable solution I see is to not allow rvalue references on this syntax but that would just feed more SO questions.

I think it is pretty safe to assume the standard committee took this into consideration.